# Day use/hourly rooms convenient to SFO or Sunnyvale?

Tags: hotels, accommodation, sfo, silicon-valley

In a few weeks I'll be travelling to Silicon Valley with a very early morning arrival at SFO and a room booked for the night at a hotel in Sunnyvale, which may not allow me to check in until 3 PM.

**Are there any day use/hourly hotels/rooms convenient to either, which cost less than just booking a full night at a regular hotel?**   The hotel I've booked offers no such option, and SFO's own Freshen Up naprooms charge a rather absurd $40/hour for the privilege, meaning 6 hours would cost me more than my hotel!

Comment: Due to idiot prudery (OMG two consenting adults might have fun out of wedlock!), hourly hotels in the USA are practically nonexistent. Day rooms typically check in 9am or 10am which is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you considered just 'adding a day' to your booking in Sunnyvale, or ask whether the hotel will let you into your room when you get there, that you would pay for an added charge (maybe half the room rate)? Are you headed to the G campus, which has its own sleep and shower areas?

Comment: I've typically booked an extra (earlier) day at the hotel and told them I'm arriving late (or early morning).  Never been a problem, but I've never received a reduced rate for it

Comment: @Dorothy I've asked, and the only option that will guarantee me a room is to pay for a full additional night.  Finding a nap room at the G campus is a great idea though!

Comment: @chx A day room from 9 AM would actually be fine, it'll be around that by the time I've gone through immigration/customs anyway.

Comment: Why was this closed for "price shopping"?! I'm asking what options exist, not "the cheapest".

Answer (score 1):

As the Freshen Up! at SFO is too costly ($40 - 1 hour • $10 per 15-minute increments first two hours and then $8 per 15-minute increment after), another option would be an airport lounge. All are airside, according to [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/sanfrancisco.htm), some have shower facilities, and access and cost varies.

Some hotels do offer day rates, often not published on its website, but when Googling hotel day rates Sunnyvale, I came across several sites that purport to find hotels at as much as 75 percent off: [DayUse](https://www.dayuse.com/), [Between9and5](https://www.between9and5.com/en/), and [HotelsByDay](https://www.hotelsbyday.com/en).

Depending on your travel plans, particularly if on business, many of the Silicon Valley corporate campuses, and certainly a special few in Sunnyvale, have their own naps rooms, sleep pods, shower facilities, gym, sauna, massage facilities, restaurants, and relaxation areas.

And, as it’s been nearly a year since you first posed this question, perhaps you could add your own response on what transpired.

Comment: Are any airport lounges accessible on arrival?

Comment: As for what happened, last time I was lucky enough to be able to check in early, but I visit regularly and there is no guarantee I can do that next time.

Comment: @jpatokal yes, airport lounges are accessible on arrival, but the issue is that they're airside, so it would have to be at your incoming terminal. If you're a member, they don't ask for flight info, nor did they when I used my Delta Amex Gold card; just a charge of $29 (that was at LAX).